# How to add python dependencies into a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I need to package and use a pip library along with all its dependencies into a single directory. I'm aware of pip's `--target` option which has so far allowed me to install all the dependencies into a single directory.

However, this is causing issues as all of the installed packages expect other packages to be installed globally i.e. they're not importing them from the current directory.

For example, if I install the package `foo` which depends on package `bar` with pip's `--target` option into a directory, `foo` is not aware that `bar` is installed in the same directory as it imports `bar` in code using something like this:

```py
import bar
...
```

Is there any way around it apart from fixing all the imports in `foo` manually?

Comment: Have you tried using virtualenv?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can use virtual environments in this case. User's code along with all the libraries is supposed to be packaged together as I described which would be a drop-in plugins for a bigger system.

Comment: This might be one of those rare cases, where modifying `PYTHONPATH` of `sys.path` actually makes sense. Another possibility would be to add a `*.pth` file into the actual `site-packages` that point to the `--target` location.